# How to create a network of stable traversable wormholes, how those WH behave when interacting with gravity and vessels, and how they look

Tags: science-fiction, space-travel, gravity, wormholes

first time poster on the world building site, and I have *several* questions about wormholes and how they work. I've been reading through the other questions tagged "wormholes" and researching elsewhere, which has provided some insights, but when it comes to wormholes, there's always understandably some speculation involved, so I thought I'd try some fresh perspectives. I've broken the following down to make it easier to navigate. Each question is followed by my thoughts on the answer, so I guess what I'm looking to know is, "How wrong am I?"

1. What I want to achieve.
2. My assumptions.
3. What is my wormhole structured like?
4. How do you create a wormhole?
5. How do you transport a wormhole?
6. How do I keep my wormhole in place?
7. Can I pass one set of wormholes through another?
8. What does entering my wormhole look like to the traveller?
9. Does the velocity of a wormhole, effect the velocity of objects travelling through them?**

**1. What I want to achieve:**

I want to create a galaxy spanning hard(ish) sci-fi that eliminates as much hand wavery as possible without the audience requiring a physics PHD to understand it. To avoid breaking causality, I've settled on interstellar travel being facilitated by a network of stable, traversable wormholes that stay open. I'd like to better understand how this could be achieved and what it might look like.

**2. My assumptions:**

From my research, to hold open a traverseable wormhole, you need exotic matter with negative mass. We'll assume our wormhole builders had access to it. We'll also assume they began building their wormhole network from one location and had to deliver branches of the network to desired locations.

**3. What is my wormhole structured like?**

I imagine the "surface" of my spherical wormhole is like an event horizon shrouding the negative mass object holding it open, like a black hole shrouding a singularity, but instead of passing within the 3D space occupied by the sphere, you exit the horizon of point B instantly as you enter point A. Does this mean that once the wormhole is created, the negative mass inside is forever untouchable by anything in 3D space? And the wormhole itself behaves as if it's a negative mass object?
[image]

**4. How do you create a wormhole?**

Maybe forcing exotic matter into naturally occurring subatomic "gaps" in space until it's enlarged to the required diameter. Then "splitting" that exotic matter and separating it to create two ends of the hole that you can pass through. Or maybe the exotic matter is somehow subjected to quantum superposition, meaning it exists in two places at once, allowing passage between those two places?

**5. How do you transport a wormhole?**

After my two ends are made, I need to move one of them to my destination. I've read that negative mass repels positive mass, but positive mass still attracts negative mass. With this being the case, can I just place an equally-sized positive mass ahead of the wormhole, pulling the wormhole in the direction I want while the wormhole simultaneously pushes the positive mass? This would lead to a runaway acceleration limited only by the speed of light. Meaning that I can transport my wormhole at almost the speed of light with zero energy input? And to decelerate my wormhole at its destination, I just need to somehow reverse their positions until they come to a stop.
[image]

**6. How do I keep my wormhole in place?**

As a negative mass object, can my wormhole have a stable orbit around objects or nearby them? I thought lagrange points might be a stable location. If a wormhole is much less massive than a planet, would a planet's dominant gravity keep it in a stable orbit? If it has to be more massive than a planet, then maybe a lagrange point or its own dedicated orbit around a star would work? One thought I had was encasing the wormhole in a cage of positive mass to give the wormhole a net positive mass for the purposes of remaining by a particular star.

**7. Can I pass one set of wormholes through another?**

Even at relativistic speeds, it takes tens of thousands of years to move my wormholes across space. Could I speed up the process by using the existing branches of my network?
For example, point A to point B is 1000LY apart and already established; now I want another wormhole pair from point B to point C, another 1000LY away. Instead of taking 2000 years to send B-C from point A, where I'm making my wormholes, can I skip half the distance by sending B-C through my A-B wormhole first and then completing the second half of the journey at relativistic speeds?

**8. What does entering my wormhole look like to the traveller?**

I imagine the sphere ahead of me taking the image of a fish-eye view of the other side, distorted towards the edge. As I pass through the horizon of the wormhole, the image ahead envelopes me, and what was behind me is now receding into the distorted fish eye image of the wormhole at its destination. But that border—does it look like a thin, bright circle of light? As if the light of all the stars between points A and B had been compressed into the edge between each end of the wormhole?
Also, if the hole is held open by a significantly large negative mass, is there "opposite" time dilation? Would crossing that horizon from the perspective of a traveller take longer than for an outside observer? If so, would the outside observer see me speed up into the wormhole and slow back down as I exit it?

**9. Does the velocity of a wormhole, effect the velocity of objects travelling through them?**

For example, point A and point B are orbiting different planets that are orbiting different stars, each orbiting the galaxy on different paths, and therefore are not stationary relative to each other; in fact, the magnitude and direction of the velocity of one end relative to the other could be massive. So does a ship passing through the wormhole suddenly experience a massive and instant acceleration in an odd direction that instantly destroys them? If so, would a ship be required to enter the wormhole at a particular speed and angle to minimise this?

Apologies for the very long read; hopefully I was specific enough and you've got some great insights! I understand that in fiction, things can be however I want, but I enjoy in-depth lore that make sense, so thank you in advance for any help!
X

Comment: Hi, thanks for the in-depth question, but on the entire Stack Exchange platform it is customary to focus on one specific problem. Of course, you can ask several, but they just need their separate "threads". Please take the [Tour] to learn a bit more about this site, and [edit] this question to focus on one problem. Thank you, and welcome!

Comment: Welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. For future reference: (a) Stack Exchange allows one and only one question per post. Multiple questions are literally a reason to close a post. (b) The [help/dont-ask] prohibits giving your own answers and asking for more. Per the [tour], SE is not a discussion forum. It appears you have answers to all your questions already. (c) Set your expectations wisely. There is a lot of mathematical predictions about wormholes, but no evidence at all that they exist. Everything you're talking about is speculative (not science).

Comment: sorry to burst your bubble but wormhole isn't a shortcut in space, you could end up much further away from the destination than you would via conventional means (in theory).

Answer (score 5):

> 1. What I want to achieve:

I appreciate the afford, but there are fundamental problems. Negative Energy is explicitly forbidden in General Relativity for complex reasons. Even outside of Relativity, Negative Mass is highly problematic. Namely the fact the only possible Negative Mass Atoms you could make would create matter that implodes into itself. You cant form stable matter out of Negative mass. For more info see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zEGsq7H5egE&ab_channel=ScienceMeetsFiction).

Another issue is that "exotic matter" is a magic term equivalent to "If we had this impossible thing that other impossible thing might work". The while Wormhole, Alcubierre Drives and so on *are* valid mathematical solutions to Einstein´s Field Equations, the general consensus among experts familiar with the matter is that a Theory of Quantum Gravity (Unifying General Relativity and Quantum Mechanics) would rule out these solutions.

So it is best to leave these elements ambiguous in your world. Just because something is a valid solution, does not mean it is physical. -5 Apples might be valid, but not physical.

> 2. My assumptions:

That is true, for the most part. I have read of some solutions that dont require Negative Energy but those are a bit much to get into. This field is constantly evolving, last time i checked up on the Alcubierre Drive i found a paper calming you dont need Negative Energy and a 100 Meter wide Warp Bubble could be sustained with ~100 kg of regular matter.

Note, when Papers talk about "Matter" in this context they usually mean Mass Energy, all $E = mc^2$.

> What is my wormhole structured like?

There are a couple of wormhole solutions. What you describe does not appear to be any of them.

Even then, there is a conceptual issue. Namely the "instantly " aspect you mention. That breaks causality. To oversimplify a lot here, there are two velocities in General Relativity. The local and coordinate velocity. The local velocity is limited to the speed of light, the coordinate velocity is not. Wormholes, Alcubierre drives etc. exploit the fact your coordinate velocity can be many times larger than the speed of light. But not infinite.

Even wormholes need some time to transport you from A to B. Since within them the local velocity still cannot go above the speed of light. If your wormhole is 10 kilometers across the absolute fastest you can go through that is the speed of light. And it will take idk 0.00003 seconds to traverse it.

> How do you create a wormhole?

Nobody knows. We dont know how to do it for "real" Metrics (Solutions to GR) and only you can know how to do it for yours. A big problem with Math is that it only tells you if something can in principle be done. Not how.

> How do you transport a wormhole?

Gravity still effects them so a Gravity tractor would work. Alternatively momentum has to be conserved so if you just shoot a laser into it the Wormhole has to move. Same way you can move a Black Hole.

This also covers your question 6.

> Can I pass one set of wormholes through another?

At the very least you can send the machinery to make more of them through the already existing network. I would however not bet on you being able to pass one Wormhole through another without them just merging.

> What does entering my wormhole look like to the traveller?

Since you have not provided math to describe the spacetime of your wormhole, this question cannot be answered. There is no real way to visualize what you want. So it is up to you.

> Does the velocity of a wormhole, effect the velocity of objects travelling through them?

Depends. Momentum is a touchy subject in General Relativity and not well defined for like a lot of cases. Having worked with fictional GR metrics i can tell you it is kind of up to you.

Momentum does not have to be conserved. If you drop something on Earth, its momentum increases so locally Conservation of momentum is kinda out the window. So it is entirely reasonable for either extreme to be the case.

Maybe the Wormhole gives some of its momentum to anything passing through such that Momentum is not Conserved, or it dosnt. Both are perfectly plausible depending on the exact mathematical formulation.

I would tend to argue momentum being conserved is more plausible. Which means if the exit B is moving relative to A, and object C going through A does not have the same relative velocity to B than A to B, it will still not have that velocity when leaving B.

Comment: This is just the right answer, +1. 
I would only say, there are some alternate formulations of GR that relax the Weak Energy Condition to allow *gravitationally* negative mass which still has positive inertial mass, avoids the contradictions and instabilities of negative inertial mass, and could potentially function as exotic matter.

Comment: Thank you so much! A lot of great informationation here. Of course I understand that a lot of what is basically magic ends up beinge involved with a subject like wormholes, especially the "creating them" part. Confirmation that they can be moved to and kept in a convenient place are the most important parts for me. I may rephrase one or two of my questions a little better in separate posts :)

Answer (score 5):

So, ErikHall's answer addresses your question well but I'd like to add a few things.

You'll read about the negative mass "requirement" for wormholes, and then about the grand cosmic consequences of negative masses. However, what you *actually* need is a negative energy density, which isn't necessarily solid stuff that can be pushed on. Wormholes require anything that violates space-time's [averaged null energy condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_condition#Null_energy_condition) (ANEC). There are a few highly theoretical options to pick from to generate exotic energy conditions:

- [Casimir vacuum.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect#) Set up two parallel conducting plates and the number of modes in the electromagnetic field between them is restricted. The plates feel a force pushing them together. In quantum mechanics, the potential for a field to vibrate is associated with a certain energy, so restricting vibrations removes their contribution to the total vacuum energy of the region. The energy between the plates is made less than the region beyond the plates, less than zero. If this energy is of the ANEC-violating kind, it could be used to support a wormhole.
  However, possible negative energy contributions from the Casimir effect would be quashed by the overwhelming positive contributions of the plates. You need to get the Casimir energy without the massive plates. It's been suggested that the warped geometry of a wormhole throat might impose boundary conditions that restrict modes of vibration, a "topological Casimir effect," and maybe this could support or help to support a wormhole.
- In space-time curved by gravity, modes of vibration become squeezed states (the effect that produces the negative energy region around a black hole responsible for Hawking radiation). [It may be that the highly-curved space in a wormhole squeezes the vacuum enough to support itself](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0003092).
- [Quantum energy teleportation.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.03805) (Sounds like technobabble but it's a real subject.) In short, it may be possible to create ANEC-violating regions with quantum energy teleportation so long as the negative energy region is surrounded by an even greater positive energy region, so that the average energy is positive.

Some formulations minimize/eliminate negative energies:

- [Fermionic wormholes](https://www.npl.washington.edu/av/altvw216.html) may not require any negative energy regions if they have the characteristics of fermionic particles and a very large charge-to-mass ratio.
- [Thin shell wormholes](https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.0907) with planar/polyhedral shapes (tetrahedron, cube, icosahedron, etc.) of sharp edges may require very little negative energy, depending on the radius of curvature at the edge. In the limit, [infinitely sharp edges have no negative energy](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.07299).

---

#### What is my wormhole structured like?

Depends on the geometry and there are many examples (like the ones above). [Thin shell wormholes](https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.0907) are two regions of space containing the same points. A point on a spherical thin shell maps directly to a point on another spherical thin shell. The space is just no longer simply connected, and moving through it is like moving through regular space. (However, if the traveler is large compared to the wormhole, tidal forces will be significant. Imagine pushing your palm through a small, spherical wormhole: you could curve your fingers into a C-shape to meet the wormhole's surface; but remember that the points are connected, the points of your palm would map directly to the points on the surface of the other wormhole, which has the opposite curvature, a backward C-shape; your fingers would emerge bent backward!)
(To elaborate on that, if the traveler is large compared to the wormhole's curvature, a significant "minimum energy" is required to push an object through. The kinetic energy of the object is partially transferred into stressing the molecular bonds making up that object. Lacking the force needed, you wouldn't be able to push your hand through the wormhole, and anything lacking the minimum energy needed to overcome the tidal force would bounce off.)

---

#### How do you create a wormhole?

[PBS Space Time made a great video about what General Relativity has to say about the structure of space on the smallest scales.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvubLp5o5Wg) At the level of quantum foam, the geometry of space-time becomes uncertain, and transitory wormholes may pop in and out of existence. To create a wormhole, one might try to "grab" one of these wormhole pairs and attempt to enlarge/stabilize them by whatever property dictates their radius & stability.

Creating a wormhole means changing the topology of space-time, from simply connected to multiply connected, which may not be possible.

---

#### How do you transport a wormhole? Does the velocity of a wormhole affect the velocities of objects traveling through them?

Wormholes would have the conserved properties of mass, momentum, and angular momentum, and would follow ballistic trajectories through space-time as if they were any object with those same properties. To move a wormhole, one must transfer momentum.
Despite what might be said elsewhere, wormholes do not automatically toss energy-momentum conservation out the window. If an object with mass M enters wormhole A and exits wormhole B, then wormhole A *gains* a quantity of mass M while wormhole B *loses* a quantity of mass M. It's as if the object had "stuck" to wormhole A while an identical object had been ejected from wormhole B. Additionally, if the object of mass M has a momentum vector P, then A gains the momentum while B gains momentum in the opposite direction (both gain the momentum vector normal to the surface of shared space coordinates), again as if the object had crashed on A while being ejected from B, in a way that is like a perfectly inelastic momentum transfer. What is true of momentum is also true of angular momentum.

The upshot of all this is that you can transport a wormhole by shooting stuff through it. A stream of matter (say, rocket exhaust) shooting through A, emerging from B, will propel B as if it were a rocket. It will also propel A in the same way, but one can counteract this by rotating A and applying thrust in the opposite direction, though through the same set of points relating to B.
Wormhole B basically becomes a rocket obeying the [Tsiolkovsky rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation). If 1,000 tons of propellant are blasted through B, B loses 1,000 tons (well, it really loses the total mass-energy content which starts to matter when things go relativistic, like shooting particle beams or lasers through instead).

Wormholes will also conserve charge. Pass a stream of electrons out of a wormhole and it takes on a positive charge. Momentum can then be transferred by electromagnetic forces.

[image: gl charge conservation]

*(Source: [Galactic Library](https://www.galacticlibrary.net/wiki/Wormholes#Fields_and_conserved_properties))*

---

#### Can I pass one set of wormholes through another?

Yes, you could. If the wormhole being passed is small enough to fit through without being upset by tidal forces and such. The smaller wormhole is just following another path through relatively flat space.

Comment: This is probably the closest explanation that I have in mind. I am especially impressed at your take on the effect of transporting masses between the wormholes. Indeed mass cannot simply disappear at one point and appear at the other, so the mass of the wormhole must change at their mouths. One thing you haven't touched is the case where the "age" of the wormhole mouths differ due to one of them being transported somewhere at relativistic speed, hence subject to time dilation. Interesting things might happen as long as we don't create a closed time loop.

Comment: @HendrikLie Thanks! I wanted to include a section about time dilation and the mechanics that might prevent CTCs, but ran out of time to write the answer (plus, it's already somewhat lengthy). But because OP asked about wormhole networks, I think it needs addressing. I might go back and edit later.

Comment: I absolutely love this answer thank you! My original post was going to be a lot longer (glad I trimmed it down!) and I was going to ask about tidal forces on larger objects. The fingers bent the wrong way analogy is a great way to visualise it. The quantum foam wormholes is exactly what I was thinking when I mentioned forcing exotic matter into subatomic gaps in space so it's great to get some further info on that.

Comment: Also really like the idea for transporting wormholes. It sounds like given an enough uses a wormhole in a stable orbit will be moved out of position so I could imagine whatever civilisation is governing their use would have to ensure regular traffic travelling in opposite directions to avoid disrupting the wormholes stability too much, or else have to compensate by way of firing an exhaust plume into it from one side on occasion. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

### 3D Wormholes can't be traversed:

A 3d Einstein/Rosen Bridge (wormhole) is untraversable. A wormhole is basically just a black hole that connects to another area of spacetime; so, if you were to enter a 3d wormhole made of positive mass, your ship would be crushed as the vectors of gravitational forces converge and all that would be left of your ship to come out of the other side would be a blast of radiation.  If instead you made your wormhole out of negative mass, you could not pass the event horizon regardless of its shape because it would repel you at the speed of light.  But... if you can make a black hole flat, then the vectors of gravity become parallel allowing you to enter it without crushing.

[image]

### How to make wormholes from blackholes:

A black hole is not necessarily a perfect sphere.  Blackholes can have spin which flattens them out ever so slightly, but the way that normal blackholes are made makes spinning them enough to have a perceivable effect unimaginably hard... but what if you started off with a tiny blackhole?  There are, in theory, primordial blackholes that can be way less massive than stars, even microscopic.  So, if you were shoot a laser at a tangent to an event horizon, then you could spin the black hole while building up a ring of massless energy around it.  So with a powerful laser, you could stretch it out into a very thin sheet big enough to pass a ship through without crushing it.

### How connecting them works:

The hardest thing about wormholes to resolve in any setting is explaining how you connect two black holes.  But what if they are already connected?  Primordial black holes could be created already connected and stabilized by negative mass that they absorbed during the creation of the universe.  Negative mass is too unstable to still exist in normal space today, but inside wormholes the negative mass is stabilized by the effects of being sandwiched between the two black holes permanently pinning two areas of spacetime to one another.

### Building your Gate Network

Imagine that our solar system is filled with trillions of low mass microscopic primordial black holes.  Since space is mostly empty, most of these black holes just orbit the sun like any other little bits of space dust, but since these guys are connected to other random parts of space, the need to transport them is a non-issue.  Instead, gravitational effects on the far end could cause small variations in the path of these micro black holes that are near other star systems.  So, if you could map out all of the micro blockholes in a star system, you could see based on thier paths which ones empty out into "interesting" parts of space and open them up.

So, you could selectively open wormholes out of the countless options connecting only areas of space that are near star systems. You never know just where a wormhole will take you until you open it, but as long as it is to somewhere near enough to another star, there is a good chance that it is a place worth exploring and colonizing.